# Angular2/4, when press enter in input, unrelated (click) is fired in another button element

Tags: angular

Angular2/4, when press enter in input, unrelated (click) is fired in another button element

```
  removeCampaign(){
        alert('wow, why am I jumping')
    }
```

gets invoked

see here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/BYKIItI9SdNSeUg9LYbg?p=preview

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution, need

```
<button type="button" (click)="removeCampaign()" class="btn btn-danger">
```

type=button